# Is it possible to insert timestamp in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to have a column in which the default timestamp is added when an insertion is done. I have done that in MySQL using choosing default timestamp option. How do I do that in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [CreationTimeStampUTC] DATETIME DEFAULT(GETUTCDATE())
```

Or you could do the same with `GETDATE()`, which I think I've seen more in real-world code. Note, of course, that `GETDATE()` will be valued with the current server time of the SQL Server, and may or may not match up with the current time of the web server if you have one, or particularly the client's machine. Obviously there's no issue with that, just make sure you're aware of the implications ahead of time. You could also store this timestamp as a `DATETIMEOFFSET` to rid yourself of some of those concerns, but since you're speaking explicitly of on-server default values, I think UTC is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: FYI, SQL Server supports default values other than constants.

Comment: @DMason Oh hey, you're right. Even better. Thanks. I never actually read the documentation's definition of "constant expression," so I didn't know they counted system functions in that. Learn something new every day. I'll adjust my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: By default timestamp, I mean the current time at which the a row is inserted. I need the current timestamp.

Comment: @Rahul yes, is that not what this does?

Comment: @Rahul, SQL Server has a data type named `timestamp` (it's the same thing as the `rowversion` data type.  However, it's not really a "time" or "date" data type per se.  In SQL Server, [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) used for storing dates and/or times include `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2`, `SMALLDATETIME`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD InsertTime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()

Comment: I've tried this. But i get "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users_Master' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: @Rahul odd..  can you post your schema definition?

Comment: and the exact statement you executed

Comment: @Rahul your `INSERT` statement that you tested with included a value for the `IDENTITY` column. Try testing without specifying that column and it should work.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Thanks a lot. Got your point.. It is working :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a default constraint. How you add it depends on whether the column already exists or not. If it doesn't, you can add the column and the constraint in one shot like so:

```
alter table dbo.yourTable 
   add [NewColumn] datetime 
   constraint [DF_NewColumn] default (getdate());
```

If the column already exists, you can attach a default to it like so:

```
alter table dbo.yourTable
   add constraint [DF_ExistingColumn] default (getdate()) for [ExistingColumn];
```

Finally, if the *table* doesn't yet exist, you can add the constraint to the table definition:

```
create table dbo.yourTable (
    NewColumn datetime not null constraint [DF_NewColumn] default (getdate())
)
```

Note: in all cases, I gave the constraint a name. You can choose not to, but then you'll eventually get a huffy DBA asking why her database comparison is a mess because the constraint names don't match up between dev and prod. :)